# Eval_training_Data uses full training data or not

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection-api

In Tensorflow Object Detection API, when eval_training_data is set to True, whether the evaluation results will be for the entire training data or a part of training data with [num_examples in eval_config?](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config#L180)

I am writing a code using the legacy script to do both evaluation on training data and validation data.

Answer (score 0):

evaluation should only be executed on the test.tfrecords that you have generated. It should not be something the model have been trained on. Testing on sth the model don't know will strongly evalutate the performace of the model.

The num examples will restrict the amount of example you take from the evaluation tfrecord to evaluate. Here is 1000 and repeat taking again 10 times. Therefore, it will have randomness in the evaluation. Just like batching in training

```
eval_config: {
 metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 1000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "path_to_test*.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "path_to_labelmap.pbtxt that you use to train"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Comment: The doubt in over here is when eval_training_data flag is set to True. During that time, what will be the num_examples value we have handled.

Comment: As I said, it depends on how much data you want to evaluate. If you have 10 thousands image testing data, 1000 is enough to take evaluation due to the recursiion 10 times. It will faster the evaluation as well as creating randomness.

Comment: a fraction 1/10-1/3 testing data is ok to my opinion

Comment: Testing data is not an issue. The main question is related to eval_training_data parameter, which will be used to provide the evaluation result on training data. I know that evaluation normally happens only with the test data. Since tensorflow guys have provided an option for training data evaluation, I wanted to know how it works and if so, I can use it for my training. Because, the current training curve, is based on the individual steps and step wise loss in Object Detection API. I want it for like a complete epoch.

Comment: ah, I see, I think you should create another question to avoid the misleading. The title should be like "Adding validation at the end of epoch for Tensorflow API". Throughout reading the train.py in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py#L183 and track back to the configuration file, the way they design eval and train config is separtely execute. Train config will be used when you run train.py and eval config will be used when you run eval.py

Comment: You may have rewrite the training process by yourself instead of just passing parameters in config if you want to evaluate every epoch. You can read the eval.py and train.py to understand the idea in here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/